# Sqlite primary key on multiple interchangeable columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Can you specify a primary key to be multiple interchangeable columns?

I have created a table that stores friendships between users:

```
CREATE TABLE FRIENDSHIPS (
    AN_USER_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    ANOTHER_USER_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AN_USER_ID, ANOTHER_USER_ID)
);
```

I don't want to have duplicated friendships so if there is an entry like: 'John', 'Jack' I don't want 'Jack', 'John' to be added.

What's the best way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: This is a faq. Eg google 'stackoverflow sql symmetric relationship''.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way to achive that through `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints only. You could use trigger though (in addition to the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertCheck
BEFORE INSERT ON FRIENDSHIPS
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'There can be only one combination.')
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM FRIENDSHIPS
                  WHERE ANOTHER_USER_ID = NEW.AN_USER_ID AND AN_USER_ID = NEW.ANOTHER_USER_ID);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you do not have duplicate pairs, you could add the constraint that the first values must always be smaller than the second value:

```
CREATE TABLE Friendships (
    A_User_UD       TEXT NOT NULL,
    Another_User_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (A_User_ID, Another_User_ID),
    CHECK (A_User_ID < Another_User_ID)
);
```

Comment: My problem here is that I won't always have both combinations. If you are friends with Jack and John, both will tell you of their friendship, but if you only know John then you wouldn't know he's friends with Jack.

Comment: But I guess I could order the strings before inserting them in the table.